# Hide Site Assets library from site contents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, wiki-pages

I am making a very simple wiki pages library (site members edit the wiki pages and add pictures etc...on the wiki pages.

But we don't want them to see the Site Assets library when they go to site contents.

or

The idea is to stop people from adding the documents directly in the Site Assets library and/or use as a document library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint Designer has the setting "Hide from Browser' to hide the List/Library from browser.

It only restrict the user to view the List/Library links from browser,but if user directly use the URL to reach that List/Library and the user can edit or add new items.

Better set the ready only permission to users and set the "Hide from Browser" to the Site Assets library through SharePoint Designer.

Follow the steps to hide the Site Assets Library through Designer:

1. In Site Object Section, Select Lists and Libraries
2. Select Site Assets Library on right side, it's navigate to List Settings
3. In List settings-> General Settings,
   Uncheck option “Display this list on quick launch”. [This is necessary],
   Check the “Hide from browser”.
4. Save the list.

Now the links are hidden from SharePoint Site in browser.

Follow the steps to Unhide the Site Assets Library through Designer:

1. Open SharePoint designer 2010.
2. Click the “All Files” folder at the bottom in left pane.
3. Right click your hidden list from “All Files -> Lists”
   folder and choose property.
4. Now you have your hidden list open in SharePoint Designer.
5. In List settings-> General Settings: Uncheck the “Hide from
   browser” and save.

Now the links are visible in SharePoint Site.

Comment: Thank you Shantha Kumar, it works perfectly using SharePoint designer 2013. We need to only hide, as ready-only permission to that folder will stop users to add pictures/documents while they edit the wiki pages.

Comment: Actually, for this question, since the only requirement is to prevent users from adding things to the Site Assets library, all that's really needed is to set the standard users' permissions to Read.  If you do this, but still leave the Site Assets library un-hidden, it can make things easier for the small group of users that are actually *supposed* to have Contribute access to Site Assets. ...Actually, I'm going to go ahead and post that as an alternative answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint Designer 2010 there is an option to hide the list/library from the browser. I'm not in front of SharePoint Designer 2013 right now, but I'm fairly certain that it exists there as well.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers that suggest hiding the library from the browser are good, but since your stated motivation is that basic users are putting things into Site Assets as if it were a typical document library, all you really need is to set permissions on the Site Assets library.

I'll give an example of a permissions strategy for a very basic site, to help illustrate.

Suppose you have the following groups:

> - Owners
>     2 people, they have Full Control at the site root
> - Members
>     40 people, they have Contribute at the site root
> - Visitors
>     250 people, they have Read at the site root
> - Designers
>     5 people, they have Design at the site root
> - Team A
>     10 people, they have no permissions at the site root (all are also in Members)
> - Team B
>     10 people, they have no permissions at the site root (all are also in Members)

and you have the following content:

> - Various lists
>     Permissions may vary per list.
> - Shared Documents
>     Inherits from root.
>
>   - Team A Docs folder
>       Members and Visitors removed, Team A gets Contribute.
>   - Team B Docs folder
>       Members and Visitors removed, Team B gets Contribute.
>   - Public folder
>       Visitors changed to Contribute.
> - Site Pages
>     Members changed to Read.
> - Site Assets
>     Members changed to Read.

The key here is the last two changes. Most of the site's users have not bothered to learn enough about web parts, wiki editing, and CSS/JS to have any reason to edit the site's pages or modify the Site Assets content, so let's stop them from potentially breaking the nice pages you've built, as well as preventing them uploading their Word documents into the Site Assets library.